# Java array for object from created class

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, methods

I've created class below and launch code in java project for 2 employees. 
How I should modify class (mandatory to use private attributes and public methods ) and code in order to use this class in project where I should implemented arrays.
Idea is to launch e.g loop 10 times and to print output for all assigned values.

Class

```
package radomirbz4;

public class RBZ4C {



private String Employeename ;
private   String JMBG;
private  Double Salary;
private int Experience;

void newName(String newName) {
    Employeename = newName;
}
 void newJMBG(String newJMBG) {
    JMBG = newJMBG;
}
void newSalary(double newSalary) {
    Salary = newSalary;
}

void newExperience(int newExperience) {
    Experience = newExperience;
}

void printChanges() {
    System.out.println("Employee: "+Employeename+"with JMBG: "+JMBG+"has salary"+Salary+"due experience of"+Experience+"years.");
}
```

}

Code

```
package radomirbz4;
public class RadomirBZ4 {



    RBZ4C employee1 = new RBZ4C();
    RBZ4C employee2 = new RBZ4C();

    // Invoke method on each objects
    employee1.newName("Radomir Brzakovic");
    employee1.newJMBG("1301976761018");
    employee1.newSalary(80000.67);
    employee1.newExperience(10);
    employee1.printChanges();
    employee2.newName("Zoran Nikolic");
    employee2.newJMBG("13019760950720");
    employee2.newSalary(200000.67);
    employee2.newExperience(35);
    employee2.printChanges();
}
```

}

Comment: @Joakim Danielson-my idea was to push system to ask me to enter all data for each new member of array. In any case you may see that another guy has understood and answered perfect. Instead to answer or wait for my feedback, your huge contribution was to gave mark -1.

Comment: @Joakim: Sorry in that case. This was some kind of test. I've successfully created class and call methods twice in project, but when I've tried to define array I have had problem. I've tried in class to use this and define variables as final. Print for length in that case worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to put your RBZ4C objects inside an array in the RadomirBZ4 class like so:

```
List<RBZ4C> employees = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10) {
     employees.add(new RBZ4C());
}
```

After this you can run your methods on the elements like so:

```
employees.get(0).newName("Radomir Brzakovic");
```

And if you want to print out the date for all employees you can do it like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
     System.out.println(employees.get(i).printChanges());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will use your suggestion due for me could be to complicate to push system to insert all data for each new member of array.